# How derivation map for Differential algebra can be defined?

Tags: lie-algebras

A Lie λ-diﬀerential algebra is a Lie algebra L with a linear operator D : L → L
satisfying the diﬀerential relation

$D([xy]) = [D(x)y] + [xD(y)] + λ[D(x)D(y)], x, y ∈ L. $

How derivation map can be defined on Lie λ-diﬀerential algebra?

Comment: Could you give more context? e.g. what you mean with "derivation map on Lie $\lambda$-differential algebra", or what makes you suspect that it can be defined/what for you need to know this.

Comment: By derivation, I mean:  for Lie algebra L which we have $D: L \to L$ satisfying D[x,y]=[D(x),y] + [x,D(y)]. Is it possible to define a dertivation map like Lie algebras?

Comment: You can define a derivation for any Lie algebra. Here you should distinguish between the special operator $D$ and other derivations $d$, where you just view your algebra as a Lie algebra. Do you have a reference for such algebras? I only found [this article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081087.2020.1753641?journalCode=glma20).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I could not find any reference for that. Thank you for sharing the reference. I understood.